# How to dynamically get checked value from multiple radio groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, radio-group

I got multiple radio groups with the same name and an id number in it. (group1, group2, group3...) to get one value:

```
var value = $('input:radio[name="group1"]:checked').attr("value");
```

If i know the id number of the group where I want to get the checked attribute how do i get it?

```
var i = 2;
var value = $('input:radio[name="group" + i]:checked').attr("value");
```

not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a variable, you cant put it in the string directly.

Use string concatenation to concat the `i` with the string segments:

```
$(':radio[name="group' + i + '"]:checked').val();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz66U/

Note: You can select `:radio` without using `:input`

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the `concatenation` properly,

```
var i = 2;
var value = $('input:radio[name="group"' + i +']:checked').val();
```

And to retrieve the value, you can use `.val()`